# how to hide some links in side menu disable for some pages in ionic angular js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

Hi I want hide some links in side menu in ionic frame work. Like some users dont have permission to access some links. So I want to hide some links in my side menu for some users.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ng-if directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Just set a variable in your $scope or $rootScope, and apply the ng-if in your html code like this.

```
<ion-item ng-if="show === 1">
 </ion-item>
```